# Extracting data from sub table

Tags: sql

I have two tables Choice(column: id, choice) and Choices(column: choice_id, question_id + more).

I need to get the content of the choice column plus the rest of the columns in Choice table. I tried this and several other strings. I got nothing bot errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM Choice 
WHERE id=(select choice from Choices where question=" & request.form("id") & ") 
ORDER BY Rand()
```

Comment: give sample data and sample result

Comment: Your WHERE clause makes no sense. You're trying to compare the ID but you're fetching the CHOICE column in the SUB-QUERY. This looks like it could be done using a JOIN query instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what language you're writing this in as your tags only specify SQL.

It doesn't look like you're providing the entire snippet as from what I'm looking at you have unclosed quotation marks... or something.

Additionally, why not do a join on the two tables rather than putting a subquery in your where clause?

From a strictly SQL perspective, if i'm understanding your schema correctly, you could do:

```
declare @id int
set @id = 42

SELECT  c.*
from    Choice c
inner   join Choices cs on c.id = cs.choice_id
where   cs.question_id = @Id
```

Comment: Ok I tried the suggested

sql_choice = "SELECT * FROM choice inner join choices on choice.id=choices.choice WHERE choices.question=" & request.form("id") & " order by Rand()"
  
  
Set RSchoice = MyConn_RQ.Execute(sql_choice)


response.write(RSchoice("choice"))

It gives me the ids from the choice table and not the choice column.

Comment: Sorry, again I'm not clear on what language you're working with, but if your RSchoice("choice") is giving you the entire choice table, is the syntax for grabbing a specified element of the choice table "Choice.choice"? Or, rather than selecting *, can you select only the choice column as it sounds like that's the data you want to work with?

Comment: It is ASP classic. 
I tried the Choice.choice but that gives me an error and selecting only the choice column gives the error that the item doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried using SELECT Choice.choice AS c, Choices.* and that seems to do it for some reason.